# Is it possible to map a network path to any cloud storage hosts?

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage, google-drive

I use Microsoft SkyDrive and Google Drive.

I was wondering if it was possible to map to a folder on a cloud service via FTP or something similar? I don't see any obvious ways on Google, or SkyDrive web sites.

I know they each have their custom applications to access the cloud storage files. But my network admins block traffic on those applications. So I was looking for another way to access the files (not through the web site either).