# Cloud Storage Map to Network Drive

Tags: nas, cloud-storage

I've been trying to find a cloud storage provider that can provide direct access as a mapped network drive. Are there any cloud storage providers that allow you to map a network drive over a protocol like SMB/CIFS? Services like OneDrive, Dropbox, or Google Drive don't provide the low-level clientless access that I'm looking for, or the reasonably-priced capacity (TBs).

I need a storage provider that allows for the storage to be mapped as a network drive, preferably without the need for any local driver or client software. How can I get a few terabytes of network storage without the need to host my own hardware or virtual machine?

Edit: [This related question](https://superuser.com/questions/508785/is-it-possible-to-map-a-network-path-to-any-cloud-storage-hosts) appears to ask the same thing, with no such answers.

Comment: SMB over WAN is not a good idea. SMB will work that way, but it was not designed for WAN/high latency links. Your transfers will be much slower than if you used FTP or HTTP. SMB is also not very secure, so a WAN facing SMB share is a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I know of one solution but it is not free nor is it cheap. Check out CloudBerry Drive.

Here's a link to their site:

CloudBerry Drive
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/map-google-cloud-storage-network-drive.aspx

Comment: A $30 license wouldn't be bad except that it's per machine, which very quickly becomes cost prohibitive.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

Try ***DriveHQ***. It is FREE! You can do WebDAV Drive Mapping with it and windows will treat it like a network drive! You get free FTP too! The link is http://www.drivehq.com/

Hope that answers your question.

Jason